# How to print test summary using boost unit test

Tags: c++, boost-test

Is there a way to print a summary of the tests run in boost unit test. In particular, can a listing of the failed tests be made?

I'm having a hard time locating failing tests in the output (especially when the tests have their own output). I already set BOOST_TEST_LOG_LEVEL in order to show enter/exit, but that isn't enough to locate the failing tests.

Comment: Are you using the test log:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/test/doc/components/utf/components/test_log/index.html?

Comment: No. I'm not using that log facility.

Comment: Logging is perhaps *the* way to get test results.

Answer (score 8):

Use the option: `--report_level=detailed`

It will report all your tailing test cases and suites.

Comment: Only slightly better. This report is still many pages long and makes it hard to find the failures -- it also doesn't show the full suite/test name clearly.. I was hoping for a report that makes failures easy to spot.

Comment: You are free to implement your own report formatter. An interface should be easy to follow. Once you have that you can install it in setup step and enjoy an output of your choice.

Comment: The XML output option may make it even easier to parse/identify the fail records.

Answer (score 1):

I like the --report_level=short option

```
Test module "Main" has passed with:
    796 test cases out of 796 passed
    75790 assertions out of 75790 passed
```