# Where to find the parsed Boost.Test output in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt, boost-test

There is already a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491380/how-to-process-boost-test-output-with-eclipse) that partially answers my question .

On Eclipse 3.7.2 I followed the approach provided there and I could successfully accomplish the steps creating and setting up a new error parser and adding it to my current project. After executing my Boost.Test (boost rel. 1.48.0) Unit Test, on the Eclipse console I get the same output as the output I get when no parsing is done (e.g. when executing the Unit Test outside Eclipse (e.g. on a Linux terminal)). I searched for a new Eclipse console where the parsed Unit Test output could be displayed (similar to the consoles by e.g. gcov, gprof or cppcheck in Eclipse) but found nothing alike.

Where should the parsed unit test output be displayed? In case the parsed output shall be displayed in the Eclipse Console view, are there any suggestions what might have gone wrong with the parsing in my case?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Thanks to casperOne and kleopatra for teaching me manners.

Comment: My primary aim was to get a test report (summary) of which tests have passed and which not. I achieved this by simply adding "--report_level=detailed" parameter to the test execution. I came across this in this source [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620712/how-to-print-test-summary-using-boost-unit-test). Thanks to Gennadiy.

Comment: Does that answer your question then or are you looking for more?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse there is also a really nice plugin called [TestRunner](https://github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/wiki/Tutorial) for running CDT unit tests much like Java or Python unit tests. It handles the unit-testing parsing for you. You'll get a separate console window for your unit tests and it arranges them with level filters. Clicking on an error/warning takes you to the unit-test line number in your editor. You also can set the verbosity level as well as a few other settings from inside Eclipse.

You can directly install the plugin by using the following link in Eclipse updates https://raw.github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/tests_runner_demo/testsrunner/org.eclipse.cdt.testsrunner-updatesite/site.xml

Answer (score 0):

In order to eclipse parse errors, the error must be print in the console view at compile time. If you are emitting errors in runtime, you must add your program to be called by the Makefile.

That's how I do in embedded systems.